# MySQL Query not returning expected results

Tags: php, mysql

Lets say I have the following information in a table.  -1 means Unlimited

```
Price    Minutes    SMS    Data
7.50     200        -1     250
10       250        -1     1000
12       250        -1     -1
```

On my form I've got a number of fields and a checkbox if you want Unlimited of something so I have an SQL query which has a few variables depending on if the checkboxes are ticked like so:

```
//check to see if minutes is set as unlimited. if they are, set sms as -1
   if ($minunlim=="on"){
    $minquery = "minutes = -1";
    $minutes = "Unlimited";
   } else {
        $minutes = $_GET["minutes"];
    $minquery = "minutes >= '$minutes' OR minutes = -1";
   }

//check to see if sms is set as unlimited. if they are, set sms as -1
if ($smsunlim=="on"){
    $smsquery = "sms = -1";
    $sms = "Unlimited";
} else {
    $sms = $_GET["sms"];
    $smsquery = "sms >= '$sms' OR sms = -1";
}

//check to see if sms is set as unlimited. if they are, set sms as -1
if ($dataunlim=="on"){
    $dataquery = "data = -1";
    $data = "Unlimited";
} else {
    $data = $_GET["data"];
    $dataquery = "data >= '$data' OR data = -1";
}

//run query
$getprices = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM gg_Crates WHERE 
    price <= '$price' AND $minquery
    AND ($smsquery)
    AND ($dataquery)");
```

So my criteria I used is Price = 36, Minutes = 100, SMS = 200, Data = 300 and my expectations are the in this instance, the only items returned would be row's where the price is 10 and 12 (because data is below 300 on the first row)

The query it outputs is:

```
SELECT * FROM gg_Crates WHERE price <= '36' AND minutes >= '100' OR minutes = -1 AND (sms >= '200' OR sms = -1) AND (data >= '300' OR data = -1)
```

In my mind that reads

> Select everything where price is lower that 36, minutes are greater or
>   equal to 100 or equal to -1.  And SMS are greater or equal to 200 or
>   equal to -1. And data is greater or equal to 300 or equal -1

There is no where in that statement where is should pull the 7.50 row as data is lower than 250.

However the actual results I'm getting are that it's returning all 3 rows.  Any suggestions?

Comment: show more code... where do you set $price, $smsunlim, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably have a problem in your logic,

this

```
$smsquery = "sms >= '$sms' OR sms = -1"
```

and this:

```
data >= '$data' OR data = -1
```

is a problematic representation, change your query to:

```
$getprices = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM gg_Crates WHERE 
price <= '$price' AND ($minquery)
AND ($smsquery)
AND ($dataquery)");
```

it will fix it

Edit K20:  $minquery needed to be in brackets

Comment: That didn't seem to fix it :(  Updated question to reflect suggestion.

Comment: then you just have a problem in your logic, think about what you really need and how do you represent this question

Comment: Well I know thats it seems like its looking at whatever the lowest figure is and pulling from there upwards.  For example, there is a row which has 100 minutes or more (7.50) so it selects that row, instead of continuing with the query.  It's more of an SQL issue as if I run that query directly I get the same results.

Comment: you are getting the row with price 7.5 because it satisfies the price <= '36' AND minutes >= '100'

Comment: but its utilising AND so therefore data must be greater or equal to 300 as well, but its not.

Comment: Edited your answer, $minquery needed brackets as well.  Query works as I expected now